# What is counterpart of Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM) for problems with continuous sample space?

Tags: optimization, references, multiobjective

I am from physics background. Right now, the optimisation problem that I am dealing with contains two objectives. I already investigated the option of single objective containing both objective as sum. And results are encouraging in certain scenarios. I want to explore more. Now, objectives are non-conflicting to each other. Hence, genetic algorithm is not suitable. I came across Analytic Hierarchy Process (AHP) method by Saaty (2008). But, this is for discrete decision space.

So, my question is, what is the correct search term to find relevant literature on "Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM)" for continuous decision space?

Comment: Actually, Multi-criteria decision-making works, but multi-objective decision-making (MODM) is perhaps more typically used when working with continuous decision spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Happy new year friend.

Comment: @jbowman I think the right approach is to use weighting method. But, how do I choose the weights? It can't be interactive. I must find a way to determine the correct weights. May be I have to consider the weights as optimisation parameters.

Comment: That's basically a business / customer decision, more than anything else.